# Case-when string matching

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, matching, case-when

I have a df(Below) and a vector as c("B", "F"), I want to first split the df as list based on ID and  then if any of the values in column "Name" matches in the vector c("B", "F") then assign column "Final" with that particular value in the vector for all rows.

```
ID  Name
1   A   
1   B   
2   C   
1   D   
2   E   
2   F
3   C
```

what I have tried till now is below :

```
df_list <- dlply(df, "ID")
df_list_2 <- lapply(df_list, transform, 
                                  Final = case_when(
                                     sum(str_count(grepl(Name, "B"))) >= 1 ~ "B",
                                     sum(str_count(grepl(Name, "F"))) >= 1 ~ "F",
                                     TRUE ~ "No"))
```

My Final result should be as below

```
List 1 :

ID  Name    Final
1   A         B
1   B         B
1   D         B

List 2:



ID  Name    Final

2   C         F
2   E         F
2   F         F

List 3 :

 ID Name    Final
 3      C       NO
```

This is just a sample data, I have to run this on million of records with the vector list containing  about 20 string values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R idea based on your description,

```
lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(i) {
       i1 <- i$Name[i$Name %in% v1]; 
       data.frame(i, Final = replace(i1, length(i1) == 0, 'NO'))
      })
```

which gives,

```
$`1`
  ID Name Final
1  1    A     B
2  1    B     B
4  1    D     B

$`2`
  ID Name Final
3  2    C     F
5  2    E     F
6  2    F     F

$`3`
  ID Name Final
7  3    C    NO
```

**DATA:**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), Name = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "C")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")

dput(v1)
c("B", "F")
```

**EDIT:** If you have more than 1 final elements, then you can convert to strings, i.e.

```
lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(i) {i1 <- i$Name[i$Name %in% v1]; 
                            data.frame(i, Final = ifelse(length(unique(i1)) > 1, 
                             toString(unique(i1)), ifelse(length(unique(i1)) == 0, 'NO', i1)))})
```

Comment: Hey Sotos, Your code works perfect on the sample data but when I am applying to my original data it gives error as " Error in data.frame(i, Final= replace(i1, length(i1) == 0, "NO")) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 8, 3 "  . Kindly help me solve this. Thanks again !

Comment: You probably have more than 1 'final' elements. You can convert it to strings. Let me edit

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `group_by` from `dplyr`:

```
library(plyr)  # Load plyr first if you use it with dplyr
library(dplyr)

match_vector <- c("B", "F")

df_new <- df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Final = if_else(any(Name %in% match_vector), 
                         paste(match_vector[match_vector %in% Name], collapse = ";"), 
                         "No"))

df_new
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
#     ID Name  Final
#   <int> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 A     B    
# 2     1 B     B    
# 3     2 C     F    
# 4     1 D     B    
# 5     2 E     F    
# 6     2 F     F    
# 7     3 C     No
```

I used `paste(match_vector[match_vector %in% Name], collapse = ";")` here, which would print all matches in the Final column, if there are several. If you don't want this use `match_vector[match_vector %in% Name][1]` to get the first match.

If you need the list-structure you can then use `split` (base R) or `dlply` (`plyr`):

```
dlply(df_new, "ID")
split(df_new, df_new$ID)

$`1`
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   ID [1]
     ID Name  Final
  <int> <chr> <chr>
1     1 A     B    
2     1 B     B    
3     1 D     B    

$`2`
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   ID [1]
     ID Name  Final
  <int> <chr> <chr>
1     2 C     F    
2     2 E     F    
3     2 F     F    

$`3`
# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   ID [1]
     ID Name  Final
  <int> <chr> <chr>
1     3 C     No
```